# Как передать данные для ListView на другое Activity

Tags: java, android

При входе в приложение у меня выполняется парсинг данных с сайта и данные сохраняются в `private static ArrayList<String> names;`
Все это происходит в **AsyncTask** 
По завершению парсинга в **onPreExecute** выполняется сохранение данных и перенаправлене на Activity2  . 
Как передать эти сохраненные данные в ListView для Activity2 ?

Код первого активити:

```
private static ArrayList<String> names;

class AllStory extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();   
            Тут показываю прогрессДиалог
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String[] args) {



            try {
                Собственно парсинг

                }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            for (int i = 0; i < storyAll.length(); i++) {
                names.add(text_story); // заполняем данными
            }
И тут код перенаправления на Activity2

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо передать эти данные через extras intent-а, запускающего активити. В активити эти данные вытащить.

Может понадобиться реализовать интерфейс Parcelable для ваших данных.

Answer (score 0):

Можно иначе, если просто сохранить эти данные в базу даных, а потом в новом активити считать их в коллекцию. А если вообще по простому и не очень хорошему, то можно через статическое поле в классе.

Answer (score 0):

> И тут код перенаправления на Activity2

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList("EXTRA_DATA", names);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    startActivity(intent);
```

В onCreate() принимающего Activity (Activity2)

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    ArrayList<String> names = bundle.getStringArrayList("EXTRA_DATA");
```